# Display WooCommerce product categories names with a different background color

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

In WooCommerce, I want to display the category name on shop pages as well as a single product pages, for 5 categories, setting up a different background color.

I used the code in WP snippet code:

```php
function show_category_on_loop() {
    global $product;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
    if( $terms ) {
        $names = array();
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $names[] = $term->name;
        }
        print '<span class="category-text"> '.join( ', ', $names ).'</span>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Plus the CSS style in customizer: `.category.text {background...}`

It works, but it changes the background color on all my products.

I've also tried this code, but the result is similar:

```php
function category_single_product(){

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); 
        ?>
        <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h2>
        <?php 
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'category_single_product', 25 );
```

What needs to be added so that each category has its own style?? Thanks in advance, I'm not a programmer.

Hello. Both codes work. Thank you. But... I used the second method. But I encountered a problem - the products in the store have 3 categories added:
1 - category type - product line, i.e. name of the product line category (this is what I have currently done thanks to your help)
2 - category type - what body part it is for - BODY or HEAD values
3 - category type - home or professional use

How can you combine two categories (1) and (2) together by separating them with the special character "|" e.g. SUPER LINE | Body?
How can you add a note that the product is for home or professional use? Thank you in advance for your help.
[image]

Comment: It should be `.category-text {background...}`.

Comment: You can change the class by adding something unique for the category to it. `class="category-text-<?php echo 'somethingunique'; ?>"` The ID of the category could be used…

Answer (score 0):

first modify your php code to this:

```
function category_single_product(){
    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){
        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats );
        $category_class = strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '-', $single_cat->name ) ); // Generate a class based on category name
        ?>

        <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title <?php echo $category_class; ?>"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h2>

<?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'category_single_product', 25 );
```

then in your css something like this:

```
.category-text.books {
    background-color: #ffcccc;
}

.category-text.electronics {
    background-color: #ccffcc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add the following CSS styles in the customizer *(or in your child theme style.css file)*, defining **for each category slug** the desired color.

Here, the first rule is the default background color fallback (and text color if needed).

```css
/* Default background color (and text color) */
.product-categories > span,
.product-categories > a {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    color: #000000; /* Define if needed /*
}

/* background color by category slug (define the color property if needed)*/
.product-categories > .shoes {
    background-color:#aaffed;
}
.product-categories > .accessories {
    background-color:#fd23aa;
}
.product-categories > .tshirts {
    background-color:#f45da4;
}
.product-categories > .hoodies {
    background-color:#e45fea;
}
.product-categories > .music {
    background-color:#bbf4e5;
}
```

Then you will use the following to display the colored product category(ies) on products loop and single products, after the product title:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_colored_product_categories', 20 ); // Loop products
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_colored_product_categories', 7 ); // Single product
function show_colored_product_categories() {
    global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

    $category_ids = $product->get_category_ids();

    if ( ! empty($category_ids) ){
        $categories = array(); /// Initializing

        foreach ( $category_ids as $category_id ) {
            $term = get_term($category_id, 'product_cat');

            // On single product pages (Linked term)
            if ( isset($woocommerce_loop['total']) && $woocommerce_loop['total'] == 0 ) {
                $categories[] = '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'" class="'.$term->slug.'">' . $term->name.'</a>';
            } 
            // On products loop
            else {
                $categories[] = '<span class="'.$term->slug.'">' . $term->name.'</span>';
            }
            
        }
        print '<div class="product-categories">'.implode( ' ', $categories ).'</div>';
    }
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

**Note:** 
You can change the displayed location by tuning the hook priority in the *add_action()* function.

Comment: Hello again, how can I avoid displaying unnecessary categories in both examples.
I have 3 product categories: restore, reset, boost
I would like to add .restore ::after {content : " | BODY";} and
product-category.restore::after {content : " | FACE";}
The result must be:
for 1 product: RESTORE | BODY
for 2 product RESTORE | FACE etc.
How to do it?